# Check and prevent website ip to be used as open proxy

Tags: linux, windows, apache, security, proxy

I was reading an article in wikipedia about open proxies and in this part http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_proxy#Disadvantages it is written

> It is possible for a computer to run as an open proxy server without
>   the computer's owner knowing it. This can result from misconfiguration
>   of proxy software running on the computer, or from infection with
>   malware (viruses, trojans or worms) designed for this purpose.

ok, the viruses part I understand. But what about misconfiguration. Can someone give some examples, perhaps for most common misconfiguration issues, that can cause for my website's ip to be used as proxy. How to check on linux/windows (and if it has something to do with apache, then considering apache as well) those miconfigurations and how to fix them.

thanks